# Не получается использовать символы русского алфавита

Tags: c++

Пишу телеграм-бота на с++, при попытке написать текст на русском языке вылетает ошибка. Что изменить?

[image: фрагмент кода]
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Ну написали же: работать в UTF-8 кодировке...

Comment: У меня стоит UTF-8 кодировка.

Comment: Стоит - где?...

Answer (score -2):

попробуй изменить на setlocale(0, "")